# fancyhdr overwrites my page numbering settings

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

```
\documentclass{mwrep}

%page number on the end of chapter
\makeatletter
\let\ps@closing\ps@plain
\makeatother

%margins
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{3cm}{3cm}{2cm}{2cm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%mark
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}\lfoot{}\cfoot{}\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%mark

\begin{document}
\chapter{AAAAAAA}
\section{aaaaaaa}
\lipsum
\section{bbbbbbb}
\lipsum
\section{ccccccc}
\lipsum
\chapter{BBBBBBB}
\section{aaaaaaa}
\lipsum
\section{bbbbbbb}
\lipsum
\section{ccccccc}
\lipsum
\chapter{CCCCCCC}
\section{aaaaaaa}
\lipsum
\section{bbbbbbb}
\lipsum
\section{ccccccc}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

When you remove code between `%mark`s, you get a number on every page.
When I use `fancyhdr`, those settings are overwritten and page number is ommited at the beginning and the end of chapter. Is there a way to fix that? I'm only using `fancyhdr` to change position of page number.

Comment: What is it that you want exactly? Page numbers on the first *and* last page or just on the last, or just on the first page of a chapter?

Comment: I want page number on every page. In other words: I want the output to be exaxtly the same as if I wasn't using `fancyhdr` at all (except of page numer position of course). The problem is: `fancyhdr` overwrites my settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `mwrep` class has a very peculiar way of managing page styles, so its interaction with `fancyhdr` might be difficult; however this seems to work:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{opening}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\fancypagestyle{closing}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
```

We simply redefine the `opening` and `closing` page styles so that they use `fancyhdr` way of doing the business.

Also remove the code you have regarding `\ps@closing`.

A solution without `fancyhdr` might be

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@plain{%
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\thepage}%
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\let\ps@opening=\ps@plain
\let\ps@closing=\ps@plain
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
```

All things considered, I prefer the first solution, albeit a bit long, because it lets you customize the page style in case of needs just by using the commands provided by `fancyhdr` rather than going into low level commands such as `\@oddfoot` and so on.

Comment: It seems simpler to use `\let\ps@closing\ps@fancy` and `\let\ps@opening\ps@fancy` *after* defining the `fancy` page style.

Comment: You say that `mwrep` may not be compatible with `fancyhdr`... Is there any other way to change position of page number?

Comment: @Werner Maybe, but by defining the "fancy" page styles they are customizable in different ways.

Comment: @egreg: Nice recovery!

Comment: @Werner And Frank would be happier if less `@` are used.

Comment: So which solution is better? @Werner's or @egreg's? I does not understand what `Maybe, but by defining the "fancy" page styles they are customizable in different ways` means.

Comment: @JanAjan: egreg shows multiple, stable solutions to your problem. Mine was just a shorthand version of the first solution he provides. The shorthand makes an *exact duplicate* of the command, allowing no minor alterations. So, if you want a minor difference between `opening` and `closing` page styles (from `fancy`), then my `\let...` approach won't help. That's why he mentioned they are customizable in different ways if you define your own "fancy" page styles.

Comment: @JanAjan I've reworded the answer, hoping to have solved your doubts.